# Is %20 in site urls and and file name can create any problem on any server or browser(web/mobile) or OS or device etc?

Tags: apache, iis, xhtml, seo

Is %20 in site urls and and file name can create any problem on any server or browser or device etc ?

Is it bad for SEO ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `%20` is a [URL encoded](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_urlencode.asp) space character. Because a URL can only contain certain characters, other characters must be encoded in order to be included in a URL. For example the following text:

> this contains spaces

would be URL encoded as:

> this%20contains%20spaces

An alternative encoding for a space character is the `+` character. This often preferred because it isn't as 'ugly', a bit easiery to read, and a bit shorter. The same string encoded this way would be:

> this+contains+spaces

If you have a URL that includes the actual string %20, the % character needs to be URL encoded. The percent character is encoded with `%25`. So the following text:

> give100%20times

would be URL encoded as:

> give100%2520times

URL encoding is a standard on the internet and is required for correct operation. URL encoding should not cause any problems, however, not URL encoding will cause problems.

Answer (score 2):

It shouldn't as its standard way of encoding spaces in urls? If it did it would "break the web(tm)"

Answer (score 0):

%20 is the solution, not the problem :)